# How to properly embed JavaScript POST authentication code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, forms-authentication

I would like to insert some JavaScript on a page, I want to create an hyperlink that could help me login into a page.
So i use Embed Code

[image: Embed Code]

And I copy paste this:

```
<form id="form1" action="http://my.site.com/authentication/signin/" target="_blank" method="post">
    <input data-val="true" id="Username" name="Username" value="mybestusername" type="hidden">
    <input data-val="true" id="Password" name="Password" value="mybestpassword" type="hidden">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();">My Best HyperLink</a>
</form>
```

An hyperlink is created on the page but when I click on it it doesn't works! but if i save it on a html document it works. 
How to properly embed it?

Answer (score 2):

When using 'Embed Code' it creates a Script editor webpart/control which itself resides in the asp.net <form>, so this won't work as you can't have a form in a form. The issue is that the javascript can't select your own form (not by getElementById, not by jQuery) so the submit()-function simply doesn't exist.

What you can try is to embed the working .html-file with your code using the page viewer webpart, as this is rendered through an <iframe> which will allow the code to execute.

Comment: I've found this hack that works [link](http://webbrewers.com/adding-javascript-to-an-office-365-sharepoint-2013-public-web-page-7/) unfortunately I have this banner as I use <FORM>:
<FORM> tags are not supported in the HTML specified in either the Content property or the Content Link property. You can remove the <FORM> tag, or use the Page Viewer Web Part, which supports the HTML <FORM> tag. The Content property can be modified in the Rich Text Editor or Source Editor. More about the Page Viewer Web Part

Comment: So... Is the page viewer webpart an option like I suggested?

Comment: Yes if you embed the code from a .txt file, not from HTML